# In Qualtrics, how do I hide a slider from being displayed until a response is given?

Tags: survey, qualtrics

In Qualtrics, how do I hide a slider from being displayed until a response is given? I would like it so nothing appears but then when participants click on the scale, a slider pops up and they can drag it along to indicate how much they agree/disagree with the questions

Comment: Maybe you could delete your duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60143050/in-qualtrics-how-do-i-hide-a-slider-from-being-displayed-until-a-response-is-gi

Comment: What do you mean by "the scale"? I'm imagining multiple choice radio buttons. Do you mean you want a slider that appears when participants click on the radio buttons?